# What determines whether the Windows $Recycle.Bin folder is mixed case or all uppercase?

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

On Windows, the Recycle Bin folder is typically located right under the device root, e.g. `F:\$Recycle.Bin` or `D:\$RECYCLE.BIN`.

Windows files systems are generally case-insensitive, so in most cases it does not really matter whether this folder name is spelled mixed case or all uppercase.

Out of curiosity and because I write cross platform code that also needs to run on case-sensitive file systems:

What determines whether the folder name is mixed-case or uppercase?

Ideas are: Internal vs external, Windows X vs Windows Y, NTFS vs FAT, ...

Comment: I find this to be a very interesting question. I hope to find the answer too. (+1) from me

Comment: "Out of curiosity and because I write cross platform code that also needs to run on case-sensitive file systems:" - *So alter the path so it always has the case case-sensitivity.*  This ways you always use the same path.

Comment: I know I can easily code around this. Still, I was curious why it's sometimes mixed cased and sometimes all uppercase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any user with Administrative permissions can rename the `$Recycle.Bin` folder to adjust capitalization.

Therefore, the capitalization of `$Recycle.Bin` cannot be determined by Windows version, Windows edition, file system, or other Windows installation attributes.

[image]

For your code, I would recommend retrieving a directory list or otherwise handling the folder name in a case-insensitive way.